# asp.net simplemodal usage

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, simplemodal

I need to display an iframe either on a button click or on an event (from an updatepanel) and using the code below I should be able to do just that.

I'm just not sure how to call the JS

```
var src = "http://sample.com/";
$.modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" height="450" width="830" style="border:0">', {
 closeHTML: "",
 containerCss: {
  backgroundColor: "#fff",
  borderColor: "#fff",
  height: 450,
  padding: 0,
  width: 830
 },
 overlayClose: true
});
```

If I just have it in a `<script>` it will just display on its own.
I've had a look at the example on the main site but still unsure.

What is the syntax to call that from an event or by clicking a button/link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps, here i used a normal link. if you are using a .net button then use the

```
Button.Attributes.Add("onclick","ShowModal()");
```

test

```
<script>
function ShowModal()
{
var src = "http://sample.com/";
$.modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" height="450" width="830" style="border:0">', {
 closeHTML: "",
 containerCss: {
  backgroundColor: "#fff",
  borderColor: "#fff",
  height: 450,
  padding: 0,
  width: 830
 },
 overlayClose: true
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Works, but I am only getting the iframe, no styling seems to be applied to it, such as darken backgorund ,etc. It basically ignored the containerCss above

Comment: Add a class name to the iframe, and set the style in css, or do ou mean the model popup

Comment: Have you tried to use the modalPopupExtender from the AjaxControlToolkit?

Answer (score 1):

With button click:

```
function tocall()
{
    var src = "http://sample.com/";
    $.modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" height="450" width="830" style="border:0">', {
        closeHTML: "",
        containerCss: {
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            borderColor: "#fff",
            height: 450,
            padding: 0,
            width: 830
        },
        overlayClose: true
    });
}
```

Button's markup:

```
<input type="button" onclick="tocall()"/>
```

With some event in `updatepanel` you need handlers

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(beginRequestHandle);
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandle);

    function beginRequestHandle(sender, Args) {
        //Do something when call begins.
    }

    function endRequestHandle(sender, Args) {
        tocall()//When call ends
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var src = "http://sample.com/";
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#showpopup").click(function(e)
    {
      e.preventDefault();
    $.modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" height="450" width="830" style="border:0">', {
     closeHTML: "",
     containerCss: {
      backgroundColor: "#fff",
      borderColor: "#fff",
      height: 450,
      padding: 0,
      width: 830
     },
     overlayClose: true
    });
    });
});
```

Then adding this `<a href="#" id="showpopup">Show</a>` to your page will make it appear.

I suggest you visit http://docs.jquery.com to read up on how event triggering works.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this for calling from submit button

```
onclick = fnOpenPopUp(LineNum);
```

and to handle the modal pop up use

```
function fnOpenPopUp(LineNum)
{
    var argObj= window; 
    var detailpage = '<%=Url.Action("ReviewRequestQueuePartial")%>'
    detailpage +="?LineNumber="+LineNum.toString();

    var myWindow=window.showModalDialog(detailpage ,"ReviewRequestQueuePartial", "dialogWidth:1025px; dialogHeight:650px; center:yes; resizable:yes;modal=yes");
}
```